# Calling BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress from an instantiated class? C#

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I am writing a program that involves some heavy conversion of an Excel file into a very specifically formatted flat file. There are over 50,000 rows that need converted, so needless to say, it will take a while to process.

With that said, using a `BackgroundWorker` would make the most sense.

Everything I have executes properly and works fine except for one issue: trying to call the `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress()` method from an instantiated class to update a counter on the parent `Form`.

If I'm not making sense, maybe my code will make more sense:

The Processing GUI Form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CityTaxImport
{
    public partial class Processing : Form
    {
        string s_sourceFile;
        bool b_fileSaved;
        CityConvert convert = new CityConvert();

        public Processing(string s_incomingPath)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bg_Taxes = new BackgroundWorker();
            s_sourceFile = s_incomingPath;
            //background worker

            bg_Taxes.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_Taxes_DoWork);
            bg_Taxes.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bg_Taxes_RunWorkerCompleted);
            bg_Taxes.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bg_Taxes_ProgressChanged);
            bg_Taxes.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bg_Taxes.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            InitializeComponent();
            bg_Taxes.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        #region METHODS
        #region BACKGROUND WORKER
        //do work/runworker Async stuff
        private void bg_Taxes_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bg_Taxes = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            CityConvert convert = new CityConvert();
            convert.ConvertFile(s_sourceFile);

        }

        //when the worker completes, let user know, end program
        private void bg_Taxes_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            pb_Progress.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
            //lets the user know the file is done and prompts them on where to save it at
            if (MessageBox.Show(this, "The file has been created.\nChoose where you would like to save it.", 
                "Conversion Finished", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                while (b_fileSaved != true)
                {
                  SaveFile();
                }
            }
        }

        //used to update the progress count
        public void bg_Taxes_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           //RIGHT HERE IS WHAT SHOULD UPDATE THE COUNTER
           lb_recordCount.Text = convert.i_RowCount.ToString();
        }
        #endregion
```

And now the class with all of the hard work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace CityTaxImport
{
    class CityConvert
    {

        #region VARIABLES AND OBJECTS AND ALL THE OTHER VARS AND CHARS

        //the Excel squad
        Excel._Application xl_app;
        Excel._Workbook xl_wrkBk;
        Excel._Worksheet xl_wrkSht;


        //our friend object Type.Missing
        private object o_miss = Type.Missing;

        //dataset and table
        private DataSet ds_taxes;
        private DataTable dt_taxes;
        private DataRow dr_taxes;


        //strings and counts and stuff
        private string s_sourceFile;
        private int i_xlRowTotal;
        private int i_xlRowCount;
        private int i_dtRowCount;
        private string s_output;
        public int i_RowCount{get; set;}
        #endregion


        #region METHODS
        //the initial convert file method called by the main window
        public bool ConvertFile(string s_selectedFile)
        {
            s_sourceFile = s_selectedFile;
            CreateDataSet();
            OpenExcel();
            PopulateDateSet();
            WriteFile();

            CloseExcel();

            return true;
        }

        //builds the dataset to use
        //creates the column names that will be written into and then written to the flat file
        //SOME WILL JUST BE SPACES
        private void CreateDataSet()
        {
            ds_taxes = new DataSet();
            ds_taxes.Tables.Add("Taxes");
            dt_taxes = new DataTable();
                dt_taxes = ds_taxes.Tables["Taxes"];
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("Pr_Ward");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("Pr_Block");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("Pr_Map");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("Pr_Parcel");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("Pr_LeaseHold");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("ParFill");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("Stub");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("Pa_Amt");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("TOTFLG");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("Pr_WardBATCH");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("BSEQ");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("TRANSNO");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("TRANCD");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("Pa_BatchDate_TD");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("Pa_BatchDate_ED");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("BUSDATE");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("METH");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("Pa_Amt2");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("Payment_ID");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("OWNSEQ");
                dt_taxes.Columns.Add("Pr_OwnerInfo1");


        }

        //time to populate the dataset form the info from the ExcelSheet
        private void PopulateDateSet()
        {
            //
            i_xlRowTotal = 2;
            while (xl_wrkSht.Cells.Range["A" + i_xlRowTotal].Value2 != null)
            {
                i_xlRowTotal++;
            }


            i_xlRowCount = 2;
            i_xlRowTotal = i_xlRowTotal - 2;
            for (i_dtRowCount = 0; i_dtRowCount < (i_xlRowTotal); ++i_dtRowCount)
            {

                //this is used to make conversions of the strings to add paddings, length modifiers, what have you...
                //all that fun stuff
                dr_taxes = dt_taxes.NewRow();
                dr_taxes["Pr_Ward"] = Convert.ToString(xl_wrkSht.Cells.Cells.Range["P" + (i_xlRowCount)].Value2);
                dr_taxes["Pr_Block"] = Convert.ToString(xl_wrkSht.Cells.Range["Q" + (i_xlRowCount)].Value2);
                dr_taxes["Pr_Map"] = Convert.ToString(xl_wrkSht.Cells.Range["R" + (i_xlRowCount)].Value2);
                dr_taxes["Pr_Parcel"] = Convert.ToString(xl_wrkSht.Cells.Range["S" + (i_xlRowCount)].Value2);
                dr_taxes["Pr_LeaseHold"] = Convert.ToString(xl_wrkSht.Cells.Range["T" + (i_xlRowCount)].Value2);
                dr_taxes["ParFill"] = @"            ";//12 spaces
                dr_taxes["Stub"] = @"          ";//10 spaces ALWAYS
                dr_taxes["Pa_Amt"] = AppendAmt();
                dr_taxes["TOTFLG"] = "N";
                dr_taxes["Pr_WardBATCH"] = AppendWard();
                dr_taxes["BSEQ"] = AppendBSEQ();
                dr_taxes["TRANSNO"] = "000000000";
                dr_taxes["TRANCD"] = "P";
                dr_taxes["Pa_BatchDate_TD"] = AppendBatchDates();
                dr_taxes["Pa_BatchDate_ED"] = AppendBatchDates();
                dr_taxes["BUSDATE"] = @"      "; //6 spaces
                dr_taxes["METH"] = "Check";
                dr_taxes["Pa_Amt2"] = AppendAmt();
                dr_taxes["Payment_ID"] = AppendID();
                dr_taxes["OWNSEQ"] = "000";
                dr_taxes["Pr_OwnerInfo1"] = AppendOwner();
                dt_taxes.Rows.Add(dr_taxes);
                ++i_xlRowCount;
                i_RowCount = i_xlRowCount;
                //RIGHT HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL THE
                Processing.bg_Taxes.ReportProgress() //method
                }

            }
```

I have tried `Processing.bg_Taxes.ReportProgress();` but I get the `Object reference is required for the non-static...method` error (which I understand what that is.)

I have also looked at a lot of other Q&As on here about the using `BackgroundWorkers` however none of them seem to quite answer my question or I am just not getting it (which may be the issue as well).

My questions are, then: is there a  way to call that method without making my `BackgroundWorker` static? 
And with that: is there any problem with MAKING it static (I have always been told avoid static methods and what have you when writing code).
And finally: am I missing something in my logic here about how exactly I should be going about this? Is there another more "best practice" way?

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE**

I ended up solving my problem by just some of the essential methods over to the Form class and altering my code from there. Just wanted to throw it out there and thank everyone for pointing in me in the right directions.

Comment: You can't call the UI thread directly from the background worker thread.

Comment: You should pass an int or object value to report progress. IE `Processing.bg_Taxes.ReportProgress(convert.i_RowCount.ToString());` The general use case for this is updating things like a progressbar. Also where are you calling `ReportProgress()`?  Normally it is called in the `DoWork()` method.

Comment: @ChrisF Alright then, so that's the flaw in my logic. Now the question is, how do I get around it? I mean, there is obviously a way to do this, but I am missing something fairly important it seems.

Comment: @Jacobr365 I'll update my code to change the passing of the rowCount as a parameter.

Comment: @Gary.Taylor717 there are other questions/answers on SO that address this issue. Take a look at the ones linked to on the righthand side bar.

Comment: @ChrisF Will do. I'm just generally confused on them I guess. Relatively new to all of this, sadly.

Comment: Check this out. Good video on how to use background worker. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwlO5XYeeMo

Comment: Is there still any point to a GUI?  You just need the UI to, what, select a file  Shut it all down after that and start crunching, never make the user wait because he'll always think it takes too long.

Comment: @Hans The program doesn't just stop there. After its all said and done, the user is promoted to select a save location for the file, allowed to review it, etc. My end users, unfortunately, will think something went wrong if the program just "disappears" into the background to do its job or if I just have a window that says "please wait."

Comment: I would put the BackgroundWorker in the class instead of the method.